# Advanced array concatenation python

Tags: python, arrays, pygame, concatenation

Say I have four multi-dimensional arrays -

```
a = [["a","a","a"],
    ["a","a","a"],
    ["a","a","a"]]
b = [["b","b","b"],
    ["b","b","b"],
    ["b","b","b"]]
c = [["c","c","c"],
    ["c","c","c"],
    ["c","c","c"]]
d = [["d","d","d"],
    ["d","d","d"],
    ["d","d","d"]]
```

and I want to combine them into a single array like

```
total = [["a","a","a","b","b","b"],
        ["a","a","a","b","b","b"],
        ["a","a","a","b","b","b"], 
        ["c","c","c","d","d","d"],
        ["c","c","c","d","d","d"],
        ["c","c","c","d","d","d"]]
```

How would I do it?

*I am doing it for  spelunky-style map generation*

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
top = list(x+y for x,y in zip(a,b))
bottom = list(x+y for x,y in zip(c,d))
total = top + bottom

for r in total: print(r)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']
['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']
['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a one line instruction, that mix list comprehension, zip instructions, and list concatenation with `+`

```
[aa+bb for aa,bb in zip(a,b)] + [cc+dd for cc,dd in zip(c,d)]
```

The whole code

```
a = [["a","a","a"],
    ["a","a","a"],
    ["a","a","a"]]
b = [["b","b","b"],
    ["b","b","b"],
    ["b","b","b"]]
c = [["c","c","c"],
    ["c","c","c"],
    ["c","c","c"]]
d = [["d","d","d"],
    ["d","d","d"],
    ["d","d","d"]]
result = [aa+bb for aa,bb in zip(a,b)] + [cc+dd for cc,dd in zip(c,d)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that layout of your map is more complicated than 2x2 blocks:

```
from itertools import chain
from pprint import pprint


a = [["a","a","a"],
     ["a","a","a"],
     ["a","a","a"]]
b = [["b","b","b"],
     ["b","b","b"],
     ["b","b","b"]]
c = [["c","c","c"],
     ["c","c","c"],
     ["c","c","c"]]
d = [["d","d","d"],
     ["d","d","d"],
     ["d","d","d"]]
e = [["e","e","e"],
     ["e","e","e"],
     ["e","e","e"]]
f = [["f","f","f"],
     ["f","f","f"],
     ["f","f","f"]]

layouts = [
    ((a, b), (c, d)),
    ((a, b, c), (d, e, f)),
    ((a, b), (c, d), (e, f)),
]

for layout in layouts:
    total = [list(chain(*row)) for lrow in layout for row in zip(*lrow)]
    pprint(total)
```

**output:**

```
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
 ['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd'],
 ['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd'],
 ['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']]

[['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
 ['d', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f'],
 ['d', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f'],
 ['d', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f']]

[['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
 ['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd'],
 ['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd'],
 ['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd'],
 ['e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f'],
 ['e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f'],
 ['e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about arrays, using numpy arrays and `hstack()` and `vstack()`:

```
import numpy as np

ab = np.hstack((np.array(a),np.array(b)))
cd = np.hstack((np.array(c),np.array(d)))

print np.vstack((ab,cd))
```

Which leads you:

```
[['a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'b']
 ['a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'b']
 ['a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'b']
 ['c' 'c' 'c' 'd' 'd' 'd']
 ['c' 'c' 'c' 'd' 'd' 'd']
 ['c' 'c' 'c' 'd' 'd' 'd']]
```

Alternatively, using `concatenate()`:

```
ab = np.concatenate((np.array(a),np.array(b)),axis=1)
cd = np.concatenate((np.array(c),np.array(d)),axis=1)

print np.concatenate((ab,cd))
```

Comment: or, equivalently, use `np.hstack()` and `np.vstack()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's nifty! I changed the code accordingly.